# Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Dr Stone anime end in?

Tags: dr.stone

At the end of Season 1 of the anime Dr Stone it says season 2 confirmed (at least where I watched it), so if you want to keep following the story after that, you need to know which chapter of the manga the anime ends.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Dr Stone anime end in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weebchan was correct, to save you a few second it ends on middle of 60. So start from there, but starting from 61 like Weebchan said is also correct since there is not anything important in the second half of 60.

Answer (score 1):

Anime ends at exactly ch. 59 so you could just pick it up from Ch. 61, vol. 7

Comment: Welcome to A&M, do you have some sources to go with this statement? Also what about chapter 60?